# cancel Apple inapp Purchase api

Tags: api, rest, in-app-purchase

I need to cancel an Apple API subscription from backend (when a user deletes their account for example).

There is an API call to [verify receipts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt), but I cannot find one to cancel. I looked at [apple developer doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi) but could not find it.

Is there such an API? If not, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API to cancel a subscription. User have to do it themselves in the manage subscription screen.
For their convenience, you could provide a link to that screen in your app or via an email.